# How to use a Pandas series as a lookup for another series

Tags: python, pandas, series, lookup-tables

For two series: one with numeric identifiers and another that is a lookup associating those identifiers to names, how can I join them?  Example:

**Series with numeric IDs**:

```
data_series = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,100,5),
                        index = ["id_"+i for i in np.arange(5).astype('str')])
print(data_series)

id_0    38
id_1    35
id_2    36
id_3    32
id_4    94
dtype: int64
```

**Series with names to look up:**

```
name_lookup_series = pd.Series(['Google','YouTube','Facebook','Baidu','Wikipedia'],
                        index=["id_"+i for i in np.arange(5).astype('str')])
print(name_lookup_series)

id_0       Google
id_1      YouTube
id_2     Facebook
id_3        Baidu
id_4    Wikipedia
dtype: object
```

**Desired data frame**:

```
Google       38
YouTube      35
Facebook     36
Baidu        32
Wikipedia    94
dtype: int64
```

I am able to do this by hacking away with Pandas-fu, but this such a common `join`-looking operation I assume there is a more idiomatic way to do it.  My current method:

```
data_series.index = data_series.index.map(lambda x: name_lookup_series.loc[x])
```

Is there another way to do this, preferably with cleaner code and in one line?

Comment: *Avoid answering questions in comments.*

Comment: Will your two dataframes always be perfectly aligned on their indices?

Comment: @BradSolomon, No, that's an artifact of the MWE.  In general, the `data_series` will be larger than the `name_lookup_series`.  Also, each item in the data will have a name to look up, but there might be names to lookup not present in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename` only - because working with `index`:

```
s = data_series.rename(name_lookup_series)
#it is same as
#s = data_series.rename(index=name_lookup_series)
print (s)
Google       29
YouTube      57
Facebook     48
Baidu        16
Wikipedia    14
dtype: int32
```

Another solution - a bit complicated - is convert to `Series` and `map`:

```
data_series.index = data_series.index.to_series().map(name_lookup_series)
print (data_series)
Google       29
YouTube      57
Facebook     48
Baidu        16
Wikipedia    14
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is perfectly aligned on their indices:

```
pd.concat((name_lookup_series, data_series), axis=1)
#               0   1
# id_0     Google  13
# id_1    YouTube   6
# id_2   Facebook  22
3 id_3      Baidu  77
# id_4  Wikipedia  42
```

If it is not always aligned on index to begin with, throw in [`pd.Series.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.align.html).  This nicely gets you a tuple that you can pass to `.concat()`.

```
pd.concat(name_lookup_series.align(data_series), axis=1)
#               0   1
# id_0     Google  13
# id_1    YouTube   6
# id_2   Facebook  22
# id_3      Baidu  77
# id_4  Wikipedia  42
```